# How can I make navigation use the routes from router in ZF2.2?

Tags: php, navigation, routes, zend-framework2, breadcrumbs

We are using ZF2.2 in a project and I need to implement breadcrumbs and navigation.

As far as I read I need to define a whole navigation structure for navigation and breadcrumbs. My question is how can I force navigation to use Router routes?
Because I can't see any reason for redefining routes just for navigation.

I understand modularity and the reason why it isn't a default but I would definetely expect this functionality built in and documented, but documentation says completely nothing on using Router/Routes and Navigation/Breadcrumbs together.

Redefining routes just for navigation is not an option and it's not my decision.
Has anybody know any good solution for this?

Comment: what does the navigation has todo with routes? routes matches url to module/controller/action. Navigation is just a "tree" of your structure.

Comment: The navigation can use the routes to generate links etc, if you can post what code you have got we will have a better idea of what you need.